# How to use external python modules with NeoComplete?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-python, plugin-jedi-vim, plugin-neocomplete

After trying out many auto-completion engines for Vim, NeoComplete combined with Jedi seems like a good choice for python development. However, I can't get it to use external libraries like PySide (Qt bindings for python). Is there anyway to give NeoComplete/Jedi the location of these libraries so they can cache them?

Comment: Why not try set path command? The files under the directories set in this path will be accessed by gD as well autompletion features too.